# Java Bitset - What is the complete meaning of “Not Thread-Safe”

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, bitset

I know that java.util.BitSet operations are not thread-safe. Does only reading and writing to a BitSet in parallel threads cause a permanent(in the current runtime of application) loss of information? Or write operation executes correctly, and only the current parallel read operation may return wrong information and later read operations return correct information. In other words, I mean that, if I only synchronize the write operations and allow write operations to run in parallel with read operations, will some information still be lost permanently?

Comment: One of the issues is you don’t know. There may be one answer on your current Java installation, and different answers on other installations and other versions.

Answer (score 2):

The only thread-safe operation is read vs read: nothing is written in memory, memory can be accessed from any thread without any problem.

BUT when you have read vs write you can have surprises, ex: reading while writing may give you half the previous result and half the new result since bitfield is not atomic.

In your question, you accept that the concurrent read/write returns incorrect results in read. In that case, how do you know if the data returned by a read is correct? read many times and make an average?

So you have to synchronize your read operations with your write operations too.

EDIT: if you really want to go down the "I don't care if data is corrupt when reading" road, I suggest you add CRC to the emitted data, and you can reject the data if incorrect.

Comment: Synchronizing read operations is costly. Also, in my application, read operation is requested 50 times per second. And all the write operations happens just in the startup or occasionally at run time. In our scenario, we can also read operation returning wrong result if the data was being updated by write operation at that time.

Comment: @djaqeel - You could use a `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: ReadWriteLock is interesting when there are many readers. Not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about a standard Java library class, then you should go by what the javadoc says.

There are users out there running different JRE versions, from different vendors, on different operating system versions.  You can't rely on the behavior of `Bitset` or any other library class to be exactly the same in every environment, but you *can* rely on it to do whatever the Javadoc says it will do.

> if I only synchronize the write operations and allow write operations to run in parallel with read operations, will some information still be lost permanently?

It's highly unlikely that overlapped read operations or reads overlapped with a single write operation could leave a Bitset (or any other object) in some invalid state.  If you think that your application can cope with incorrect results that might be returned by a read, then that might be a reasonable risk to take,

*BUT*

Are you *certain* that synchronizing reads causes a performance problem?  If you haven't actually measured the performance, and you haven't found that the difference between unsynchronized and synchronized makes the difference beetween acceptable performance and unacceptable performance, then why not just synchronize all access?

To do otherwise is called "premature optimization", and more often than not, it's a waste of your own time.

Answer (score -1):

A BitSet is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization.

Please read this article for basic understanding of readers writer problem.

https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-read-write-lo

Only READing will not cause any issue in concurreny.
READ/WRITE or WRITE/WRITE cause inconsistent issues when you access the information concurrently